# Disable Html.CheckBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, html-helper, html.checkbox

I'm trying to figure out how to disable an Html.Checkbox with the given syntax:

```
@Html.CheckBox("checkbox_" + Model.QuestionId.ToString(), false, 
               new Dictionary<string, object> {{ "data-bind", "checked: $root.getResponse(@Model.QuestionId).Value" }})
```

Knockout code:

```
self.getResponse = function (questionId) { 
      var rv = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.responses(), function (item) { return item.QuestionId ==     questionId; }); 
      if (rv == null) {
          rv = new Response(0, questionId, self.evaluationId, 0, 0, '', '');  self.responses.push(rv); 
      } 
      return rv; 
 }
```

Please help

Comment: Where does $root.getResponse come from?

Comment: knockout:  self.getResponse = function (questionId)
                {
                    var rv = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.responses(), function (item)
                    {
                        return item.QuestionId == questionId;
                    });

                    if (rv == null)
                    {
                        rv = new Response(0, questionId, self.evaluationId, 0, 0, '', '');
                        self.responses.push(rv);
                    }
                    return rv;
                }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data-bind='enable : isEnabled'

You want to test if this checkbox is supposed to be enabled. I don't know your criteria for being enabled, but here is the binding for enable/disable